# monotouch DialogViewController select one or more elements

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I am currently using the advanced editing tableview as outlined in Monotouch.Dialog that allows a user to delete as well as edit the label of table elements. Is there a way to enrich the tableview to achieve something similar to the screenshots, i.e. select one or more elements?

[image: select elements]

Answer (score 3):

```
this.TableView.AllowsMultipleSelection = true;
```

to create something similar to the above i think u need to create a custom element
(maybe a subclass of checkElement)